# Как написать пользователю в личку?

Tags: обсуждение

Не смог найти "личные сообщения" Как написать пользователю который ответил на твой вопрос?

Comment: Оставите свои координаты в профиле и напишите в комментариях, что хотите пообщаться с таким-то пользователем.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Проголосовал за закрытие вопроса, но учитывая передыдущий ответ, вынужден обозначить позицию.

Нету тут личной связи. В ответах писать свой мейл не надо, это самореклама, не благославляемая политикой ресурса. К тому же такой комментарий вполне может быть удален.

У меня мейл в профиле, все, кто не против пообщаться, могут поступить так же.
Если участник не оставил адреса в профиле, значит он общаться не хочет. Это его право.

*Остальное у г-жи Аванесовой - выдумка и отсебятина. Гуглить ник в других сетях - это полнейший моветон, не вздумайте даже сказать кому-либо, что вы это делали, даже по российским законам это нарушение права на конфиденциальность личных данных, а StаckEхсhange вполне себе цивилизованный продукт.*

***А все вопросы подобного плана надо задавать на мете.***
https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

Ваш вопрос для категории "Проектная", которая здесь не предусмотрена.

Вы можете только предложить свои координаты - в комментарии к ответу, а дальше - хозяин барин.

У некоторых пользователей данного ресурса в ЛК указаны способы "обратной связи": у кого прямо-таки емейл, у меня, к примеру, ссылка на Большой Вопрос...

Так что первым делом загляните в ЛК (профиль) интересующего пользователя, а вторым - погуглите ник: возможно, он используется и на других проектах или в соцсетях.

---

Постскриптум.

Случайно увидела Ваш призыв отозваться:

> "Серж как связаться с вами? Я не могу разобраться здесь, где личные
>   сообщения?"

Под любым ответом Сержа, где нет чужих комментов, а то каша получается.

Comment: Что вы несете? Какая еще "проектная"? Вы вообще хоть какое-то представление имеете о ресурсе, куда пришли всех учить?  Вы даже профиль от личного кабинета не отличаете.

Comment: С Сержем не связываться? См. самый-самый последний коммент: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420624/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Может, уже хватит. А то надоело.